# How to draw 3D plot of interval valued function using "IntervalArithmetic" package in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-plots, interval-arithmetic

I have a function P = f(a, b, c) = squareroot( a^2 + b^2 + a*c + b*c), where a, b, and c are in intervals. I want to draw a 3D or cubical type plot where a, b, and c will be on the x, y, and z axes. My aim is to visualize how the interval value of P changes with inputs a, b, and c.

Let a = (20..30), b= (3..4), and c = (100..200).

Please note that a, b, and c are not points in some range but are intervals.

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You state that you want a, b, and c to be graphed on the x, y, and z axes. You then give a second formula for y. Is y to be the second, sqrt formula or b?

Comment: @Bill Sorry for the mistake. Please see the edited question and let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Hello Kanishk. Visualizing a 3D object on 2D screen needs some choices to be made. Do you have a specific style of visualization you are aiming for? Perhaps an image would explain it best.